# Перебор списков и нахождение элемента через *args, через цикл for, ввод пользователя

Tags: python

Есть допустим четыре списка:

```
dom = ["Кирпич", "Плитка", "Песок", "Цемент", 1, 26]
dom2 = ["Балкон", "Савок", "Веник", 45, 234, 1]
dom3 = [1, "Гвоздодер", "Веник", "Шпаклевка", "Ворота", 1]
dom4 = ["Крыша", "Фундамент", 1]
```

Пользователь вводит строку или число. Надо чтобы функция обрабатывала и принимала строку и число, сравнивала введенное пользователем элемент со списками, и функция принимала не один список.

```
subject = input("Введите слово: ")  # Ввод пользователя
def roster_main(*args):
    """Ввод слова(или числа) и нахождение его в списке, длина этого элемента,
    и определения типа элемента."""
    for x in args[0]:       # Перебор элемента в списке
        if x == subject:    # Если элемент совпадает с элементом который ввел пользователь
            print("Да такой элемент есть!")
            q = len(subject)
            print("Всего элементов -", q)
            print(type(subject))
            break
        else:
            print("Это не числа, введите строку.")
            print(type(subject))
            break

roster_main(dom)
```

Comment: напишите, что вы ожидаете получить в  вашем решении, а то   не очень понятен желаемый результат.
Лучше всего пояснения + итоговый список или  что там.

Comment: Ввожу слово или число, если есть такой элемент из 4-х списков, то выводится это же слово или число.

Comment: @ДенисЛатыпов, а откуда задачки берете, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это если достаточно первого совпадения:

```
def true_type(x: str):  # Поскольку тип данных вводимых через input() всегда будет str
                        # А в списках у нас присутствуют данные int
    try:  # Пробуем вернуть преобразованную в int строку
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:  # Есди значение не приводится к типу int значит это не число
                        # И мы возвращаем его как есть
        return x


dom = ["Кирпич", "Плитка", "Песок", "Цемент", 1, 26]
dom2 = ["Балкон", "Савок", "Веник", 45, 234, 1]
dom3 = [1, "Гвоздодер", "Веник", "Шпаклевка", "Ворота", 1]
dom4 = ["Крыша", "Фундамент", 1]

subject = true_type(input("Введите слово: "))  # Ввод пользователя


def roster_main(*args):
    """Ввод слова(или числа) и нахождение его в списке, длина этого элемента,
    и определения типа элемента."""
    for i in range(len(args)):       # Перебор элемента в списках
        if subject in args[i]:    # Если элемент находится в списке
            print("Элемент %s найден в списке %s в позиции %s" % (subject, i + 1, args[i].index(subject) + 1))
            print("Количество символов в элементе -", len(str(subject)))
            print("Тип элемента - ", type(subject))
            break
    else:
        print("Элемент в списках не найден.")
        print("Тип элемента - ", type(subject))


roster_main(dom, dom2, dom3, dom4)
```

Если нужно найти все совпадения:

```
def true_type(x: str):  # Поскольку тип данных вводимых через input() всегда будет str
                        # А в списках у нас присутствуют данные int
    try:  # Пробуем вернуть преобразованную в int строку
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:  # Есди значение не приводится к типу int значит это не число
                        # И мы возвращаем его как есть
        return x


dom = ["Кирпич", "Плитка", "Песок", "Цемент", 1, 26]
dom2 = ["Балкон", "Савок", "Веник", 45, 234, 1]
dom3 = [1, "Гвоздодер", "Веник", "Шпаклевка", "Ворота", 1]
dom4 = ["Крыша", "Фундамент", 1]

subject = true_type(input("Введите слово: "))  # Ввод пользователя


def roster_main(*args):
    """Ввод слова(или числа) и нахождение его в списке, длина этого элемента,
    и определения типа элемента."""
    index_list = [(i + 1, args[i].index(subject) + 1) for i in range(len(args)) if subject in args[i]]
    if index_list:
        for lst, ind in index_list:
            print('Элемент "%s" найден в списке %s в позиции %s' % (subject, lst, ind))
        print("Количество сиволов в элементе -", len(str(subject)))
        print("Тип элемента - ", type(subject))
    else:
        print("Элемент в списках не найден.")
        print("Тип элемента - ", type(subject))


roster_main(dom, dom2, dom3, dom4)
```

Вывод немного более развернутый чем требуется, но это не сложно исправить, отредактировав `print`

Answer (score 1):

```
subject = input("Введите слово: ")  # Ввод пользователя
def roster_main(*args):
    print(subject)
    """Ввод слова(или числа) и нахождение его в списке, длина этого элемента,
    и определения типа элемента."""
    q = 0
    for x in args:       # Перебор элемента в списке
        if subject in set(x):    # Если элемент совпадает с элементом который ввел пользователь
            print("Да такой элемент есть!")
            q = len(subject)
            print("Всего элементов -", q)
            print(type(subject))
            break
    if q==0:
        print("Это не числа, введите строку.")
        print(type(subject))

dom = ["Кирпич", "Плитка", "Песок", "Цемент", 1, 26]
dom2 = ["Балкон", "Савок", "Веник", 45, 234, 1]
dom3 = [1, "Гвоздодер", "Веник", "Шпаклевка", "Ворота", 1]
dom4 = ["Крыша", "Фундамент", 1]
roster_main(dom, dom2, dom3, dom4)
```

Можно так если верно понял что вам надо.
Если не то, то просьба подробнее описать что требутся, т.к. из Вашего описания не понятно какой нужен результат.
1. в результате тип введенного значения всегда будет строка. Даже при вводе числа, оно будет восприниматься как строка. можно проверить явялется ли числом с помощью isdigit()
subject.isdigit()
2. Всего элементов тут будет длинна введенной пользователем строки.

Comment: Если пользователь введет через `input()` 1 то это будет `'1'` а не `1` как в списке. И `'1'` не равно `1`