# Как сделать н-е количество принимаемых аргументов состоящих из множества через *args

Tags: python

Есть 7 элементов множества, нужно чтобы функция принимала любое количество множеств,  в качестве аргумента функции, 
затык у меня там где я отметил  <----- тут, не пойму как через индексы это сделать.

```
words = {'hello2', 23, 23, 'mum', 'daddy1', 'father'}
words2 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words3 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words4 = {'llo', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words5 = {'hello', 'm', 'dy', 45, 23, 'mer'}
words6 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 4346, 23, 'mother'}
words7 = {'hello', 121, 141, 1111}


# Кортеж -> Список -> Множества
def word_foo_three(*args: set):
    """Функция принимает любых два множества, преобразует в список принимаемый кортеж(args),
    перебирает одинаковые значения, добавляет в новый список и этот список преобразует в множества"""
    print((args), end=' ') , print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(args))  # изначально args кортеж
    spisok =  list(args)                                                      # преобразуем args(кортеж) в список
    print(spisok, end=' ') , print("- тип элемента: ", end=' '), print(type(spisok))   # выводим преобразованный список
    new_spisok = []              # Создаем новый список, локальная переменная
    for i in spisok[0]:          # Перебираем i в списке [1-е множество] <------- тут
        if i in spisok[1]:       # Если i есть в списке [2-е множество] <------- тут
            new_spisok.append(i) # Добавляем совпадения в новый список
    new_lots = set(new_spisok)   # Преобразуем список в множество
    print(new_lots, ",", end=' ')
    print("- тип элемента: ", end=' ')
    print(type(new_lots))
```

word_foo_three(words4, words2)

```
текущий вывод : 

#   ({'mum', 45, 'daddy', 23, 'llo', 'mother'}, {'mum', 'hello', 45, 'daddy', 23, 'mother'}) - тип элемента:  <class 'tuple'>
# [{'mum', 45, 'daddy', 23, 'llo', 'mother'}, {'mum', 'hello', 45, 'daddy', 23, 'mother'}] - тип элемента:  <class 'list'>
# {'mum', 45, 'daddy', 23, 'mother'} , - тип элемента:  <class 'set'>
```

Comment: Не очень понял, что на выходе получить нужно. Не могли бы пояснить? И в чем конкретно "затык" там, где Вы указали? Что значит "перебирает одинаковые значения"?

Comment: Нужно чтобы функция принимала любое количество множеств, сейчас она принимает только 2 множества и сравнивает их, затык у меня с индексами, через индексы думаю как бы сделать.

Comment: Через индексы множеств как элементов кортежа *args?

Comment: Я может быть чего-то не уловил, но чем эта задача отличается от [решенной ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895531/295125)

Comment: В том месте у меня списки получается, я преобразовал же. Другой вариант получается.Сейчас попробую тот кусок взять. Отличие во множествах.

Comment: Поправьте меня если не прав. На выходе мы должны получить множество элементов присутствующих во всех множествах данных в качестве аргументов?

Comment: На выходе новое множество. До этого мы перебираем множества, которое будет в аргументах

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84760/discussion-between-andrey-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Через индексы

```
words = {'hello2', 23, 23, 'mum', 'daddy1', 'father'}
words2 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words3 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words4 = {'llo', 'mum', 'daddy', 45, 23, 'mother'}
words5 = {'hello', 'm', 'dy', 45, 23, 'mer'}
words6 = {'hello', 'mum', 'daddy', 4346, 23, 'mother'}
words7 = {'hello', 121, 141, 1111}

def word_foo_three(*args: set):
    for i in range(1, len(args)):
        args[0].intersection_update(args[i])
    print(args[0], 'Тип элемента -', type(args[0]))


word_foo_three(words4, words2, words)
```